# cell editing grid loader path

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

i am using the cell editing grid in my app. The js file has this:

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../ux');
```

what will be the replacement for the relative path in my workspace?

```
../ux
```

i tried using:

```
F:\Softwares\EclipseForJavaScript\extjs-4.1.1\examples\ux
```

but did not worked

please help.

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loader does not work locally. You will need to run your application within a webser like IIS or Apache. And the the loader will accept relative paths. Relative means relative to your webserver root path/scriptpath.

Comment: I have apache tomact installed in my system. Is there some way to run it locally using the tomcat?

Comment: @user182944 I never used tomcat. With plain apache you just need to place the docs into your webrootfolder of localhost. After that you can access them. I guess with tomcat you have your default rootfilder as well.